# jQuery GMAP3 auto center after adding marker

Tags: jquery-gmap3

I have a select element with some countries, when "change" is fired, I call a function to get the coords then add the marker. It's ok but when the marker is added, the marker isn't centered.

I'm using the latest version 5.0b.

```
// get coords
$gmap.gmap3({
    getlatlng: {
        address: complete_address,
        callback: function(result){
            if(result) {
                var i = 0;
                $.each(result[0].geometry.location, function(index, value) {
                    if(i == 0) { lat = value; }
                    if(i == 1) { lng = value; }
                    i++;
                });

                // add marker
                $gmap.gmap3({
                    marker: {
                        address: complete_address,
                        options: {
                            draggable: false,
                            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                        }
                    },
                    map:{
                        options:{
                            center:[lat, lng],
                            zoom: zoom
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
});
```

I get in the console: "**Uncaught Error: Incorrect value for  : 51.919438,19.14513599999998**"

Any tips would by appreciate.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found,

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
```

Comment: This kind of only works for me sometimes, It seems it centers correctly at times, then will be off to the north by a small swipe. do you get this also?